# Angular app + NGINX + Docker

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, web

I have problem with serving Angular app using nginx on docker.
Problem is only when I want to turn on SSL on site. 
I'm using Bamboo for deployment.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.6 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
COPY ssl/certificate.crt /app/
COPY ssl/ /app/ssl

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe
RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app/
RUN ng build --prod --aot=false --env=prod

FROM nginx

RUN mkdir -p /ssl
COPY --from=node /app/ssl/ /ssl/
ADD ssl/certificate.crt /etc/nginx/certs/
ADD ssl/private.key /etc/nginx/certs/
RUN ls /etc/nginx/certs/

COPY --from=node /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN ls /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Script to run:

```
docker build -t test-app .
docker run --name test-app-cont -v /etc/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs -d -p 3010:443 test-app
```

**Deployment runs successfully, but there is no app on server served.**

Please have a look at this screen: There is listed what is in /certs and /html directories. Everything seems to be good.

[image]

If I remove these lines dedicated to SSL, everything works fine, and on server I can see my app, but only through http.

The certificates are valid, I checked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable the SSL you need to configure the Nginx for it. As far as I see in your code, you are still using the default Nginx config without any modifications. Here is an example on [how to enable SSL on Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins). The main components are:

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name jenkins.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Also I see that you mount a volume (-v /etc/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs) in the docker run command, this means that the /etc/nginx/certs in the container will be same as the host and so make sure you have the correct certificates on the host machine!